# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar un solo campo de mi registro de cualquier fila que seleccione?

Tags: php, html, mysql

En este codigo html tengo mis registros, al momento te querer ingresar el campo "folio" solo me permite recibir el valor en el ultimo de mis registros.En los primeros, solo me devuelve un valor de 0.

```
<form action="registrohistorial.php" method="post" onsubmit="return  validar()">
    <table class="striped" name="tabla" id="tabla"> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Turno</th>
                <th>Servicio</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Hora de atencion</th>
                <th> Fecha de registro</th>
                <th>Folio</th>
                <th> Estado </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php while($fila = $resultado->fetch()){ ?>    
            <tr>

                <td><?php echo $fila ['id_Turno']; ?> </td>

                <td><?php echo $fila ['Nombre_servicio']; ?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $fila ['fecha']; ?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $fila ['Hora_Inicio'], " - ",$fila['Hora_Termino']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila ['fechaRegistro']; ?></td>
                <td> <input type="text" id="folio"  name="folio" size="8"></td>

                <input type="hidden" name="id_Turno" value="<?php echo $fila['id_Turno']; ?>">

                <td><input type="submit" name="formhist"      value="TERMINADO"> </td>                                  
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</form>
```

Aqui mi código php

```
<?php
  require_once 'conexion.php';

  $folio = $_POST['folio'];
  $idturno = $_POST['id_Turno'];


        echo "folio ".$folio;
        $sqlUPDATE = "UPDATE turno SET folio = :folio where id_Turno= :id";
        $resultado = $con->prepare($sqlUPDATE);
        $fila = $resultado->execute(array(':folio' => $folio , ':id' => $id ));
        if ($fila)
                echo '<script>alert("este proceso ha sido finalizado.")</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás poniendole el mismo ID a todas las columnas que contienen el campo `folio`, por lo que al darle al botón del formulario solo te está recogiendo el valor del último campo `folio` (ya que tienen todos el mismo ID y por lo tanto no sabe cual escoger, por lo que coge el último).

Cambia el id por una clase (`class`) y podrás recoger el valor de todos tus elementos.

Comment: Cree este objeto clase, pero no se como almacenar los valores y devolverlos. class folio{

 var $folio; 

 function obtenerfolio($folio){
  $this->folio = $folio;
 }

 function getFolio(){
  return $this->folio;
 }
}

Comment: @gerardo No, perdona, igual no me expresé bien. Me refería a que tenías que cambiar el `id="folio"` por `class="folio"`. El problema es que ahora mismo todos tus elementos con `id="folio"` son, a vistas del código, el mismo elemento y es por eso por lo que solo te recupera el último valor. Cambiando id por class tendría que bastar para solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer, pero me sigue presentando el mismo error. mando a llamar 'echo "folio".$folio  y echo "turno". $id'. Para ver los valores que me devuelve. Al querer actualizar cualquier registro que no sea el ultimo, solo me devuelve el id del ultimo turno, sin folio. Pero si registro en el ultimo registro si me devuelve el folio y el turno correspondiente.